# Visual Studio 2013 locks up when files are saved

Tags: visual-studio-2013

On several PC's in my environment when Visual Studio 2013 saves files Visual Studio will lockup for a minute or more.  I ran process monitor and it appears to make the same call over an over again from lsass.exe. This same call happens on other PCs. I am trying to figure out how to resolve this issue and would appreciate any help from the community.

[image: lsass.exe repeatly makes the same calls]

Thanks,
John Ruf

Comment: It appears to be related to using configsource="xyz" in the config files.

Comment: May have something to do with the fact that the files referenced in configsource are in the bin folder.